# How to gradually increase the pixel size of an image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing, pixelation

I would like to gradually increase the pixel size of an image, going from the high resolution image (base image) to the left to a significantly lower resolution to the right as shown in the example below:

[image]
Any ideas on how to get this done?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Start with a **Base image layer**.
- **Copy base image layer** and choose `Filter > Pixelate > Mosaic` set it to some middle value and hit OK.
- Add a **Layer Mask** and draw a black to white gradient on the mask to hide a portion of the filter and show the base image below it.
- **Copy the base image layer** again and move it above all other layers.
- Choose `Filter > Pixelate > Mosaic` on the new copy and **double** the previous amount.
- Add a **Layer Mask** on the new copy and draw a black to white gradient on the mask to hide a portion of the filter and show the two layers below it.

[image]

You could actually repeat these steps as many times as you want, varying the Mosaic amount each time. The more steps used the smoother the "transition" would appear to be.

Answer (score 0):

**Filter > Pixelate > Mosaic**

Here's my base or "HD" image

[image]

Increase the Cell Size, until it looks pixelated enough to suit your needs

[image]

Comment: This was not the question asked

Comment: @BlueWizard we aren't here to hold people's hands through the entire design process. I aim simply to point users in the right direction, so they can learn the techniques for themselves.  **We are not a tutorial site**. I don't know why my answer has been downvoted (not saying it was you) or you felt it necessary to chime in, but this is certainly how to achieve the desired effect, I just didn't include the masking process

Comment: The masking is an essencial step in reproducing the effect that was requested